# Issue with login/out for 2 asp.net applications in same IIS and same db

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I built 2 ASP.NET applications, both are using the same database, including aspnet_sqlmembership authentication db. they are hosted in the same IIS in my local network, with a separated virtual directory for each one of them. I'm facing a problem that when I log in/out in one of them the other application logs out.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using forms authentication and the two apps use the same hostname. Take a look at the [configuration options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The cookie path is / by default, which means that your cookies will overwrite each other. There are many options: use different hostname, use different cookie name, use a more specific cookie path. Or if you do want to share cookies, then make sure that the machine keys are set up exactly the same in both applications (by default, they are random and not the same, so two apps can't use the same cookie). That way, if you log into one app, you will be logged into the other as well.

Comment: I tried to set a different name attribute for each application but issue still the same.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN's description of the forms configuration element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If multiple applications are running on a single server and each application requires a unique cookie, you must configure the cookie name in each Web.config file for each application.

To do this, each application should specify a unique cookie name as follows:

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms ... name="myCookieName" ...
   ...
```

Comment: I tried to set a different name attribute for each application but issue still the same.